# pass values to ngb modal angular

Tags: angular

I am using ngb modal to my project. Currently modal is loading correctly. I need to pass data inside the modal. This is my function

```
loadCheckingView(viewData, checkinview) {
console.log(viewData); // this log shows my data 
this.modalService.open(checkinview, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' }).result.then((viewData) => {
  console.log(viewData); // this log not working
}, (reason) => {

});
```

}

how I pass the data inside the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using componentInstance it worked, try Below way i hope it worked.

```
loadCheckingView(viewData, checkinview) {
   const modalRef = this.modalService.open(modelComponent);
   modalRef.componentInstance.viewData = viewData;
}
```

modelComponent.ts file

```
@Input() public viewData;

ngOnint(){
  console.log(this.viewData);
}
```